# How to zoom out on a r plot

Tags: r, plot, zooming

I created a neural network and when I made the plot, it is super zoomed in and I cannot see the side or the bottom. A shown in the photo. How can I zoom out so I can see the whole thing? I have tried using the zoom package and my mouse, I cannot seem to figure it out.

[image]

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.